# Proof that the empty type exists

Tags: type-theory

Is there a proof that the empty type exists? If there is, it's not in my textbook and I haven't been able to find one online. I feel like if it's impossible to prove the existence of the empty type, that would imply that all types are inhabited, which just can't be right. Every time I've attempted a proof of it, I've realized I indirectly assumed the existence of the empty type from the beginning, though, so I'm getting a bit concerned.

Comment: The existence of the empty type is part of the rules.

Comment: No axioms at the moment, just rules of type formation. I feel like defining the empty type without proof is too axiomatic in nature to really seem right within the type theory I'm learning.

Comment: And yet I've never seen a type theory where it wasn't a primitive type...

Comment: I'm probably just overthinking it. It's probably better to just presuppose that the concepts of true and false exist, mathematically.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine For the record, you can define the $0$ type in terms of $\Pi$ types and $\rm{W}$ types, but you do have to start *somewhere*.

Comment: @Ptharien'sflame Nifty! I'll have to look that up!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the existence of the empty type is "assumed" by the "underlying logic".

See B.Nordström & K.Petersson & J.M.Smith, [Martin-Löf's Type Theory](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~bengt/papers/hlcs.pdf) (2000) :

> The basic idea of type theory to identify propositions with sets [page 4].
>
> $A ⊃ B$ is identified with $A \rightarrow B$, the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ [page 5].
>
> The negation of a proposition $A$ can be defined by:
>
> > $\lnot A \equiv A ⊃ \bot$
>
> where $\bot$ stands for absurdity, that is a proposition which has no proof. If we let $\emptyset$ denote the empty set, we have $¬A$ is identified with the set $A \rightarrow \emptyset$ using the interpretation of implication [page 6].